# rendering data- attributes in razors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to render some `data- attributes` inside razor cshtml page

```
   <tr id="@{<text>bk</text>@f.Id}"
              data-time="@f.Time.ToString("ddd HH:mm")"
              data-bookid="@c.BookId"                                       
              @{ 
                 if (bookF > 0f) { 
                    <text>data-bookprice="@bookprice.ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)"</text>
                  }}
```

using this I'm getting compilation error

> Line 182:WriteAttribute("id", Tuple.Create(" id=\"", 1162),
>   Tuple.Create("\"", 1190)

removing this code without `<text>` attributes and using plain html works fine.

Comment: Couldn't you do something like `<tr id="@string.Format("bk{0}", f.Id)">`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the code with brackets e.g.:

```
   <tr id="<text>bk</text>@f.Id"
              data-time="@{(f.Time.ToString("ddd HH:mm")")}"
```

etc..